# Real-time log processing and alert generation

Tags: logging, stream, analytics, apache-storm, alerts

Assuming I have a continuous stream of log entries (e.g. a firewall log), I need a tool that's able to process the stream of events and do some real-time computation over it (e.g. counting the number of accesses from different IP addresses over a window of time - say 10 minutes) and trigger an alert when some condition is met (e.g. the number of accesses is > 100).

I'm aware of the [Storm Project](http://storm-project.net/), [InfluxDB](http://influxdb.org/), [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/), [KairosDB](https://code.google.com/p/kairosdb/), but except Strom they don't look like tools designed for this kind of processing. My question is if anyone knows a tool more suitable for this type of job.

Comment: I think storm is perfect for the use case you have mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You can feed your messages (log entries) to a [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) queue and integrate storm with it, there is a nice integration between storm and kafka called [KafkaSpout](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib/tree/master/storm-kafka) which is a spout that read from a Kafka cluster.

For doing a real time processing over a window of time you can check [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/) which is typically a complex event processing unit (CEP). Should be very useful for doing Event stream processing as you mentioned.

The integration between strom and esper can be found [here](https://github.com/tomdz/storm-esper). 
 And a basic [Esper](https://github.com/tomdz/storm-esper/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tomdz/storm/esper/EsperBolt.java) implementation sample

Answer (score 1):

We are using [Storm](http://storm.apache.org/) (combined with Kafka) for similar jobs and like using it a lot. The errors generated by the tool are always as helpful and descriptive as one might hope, but, overall, once overcoming those, it provides a very solid and robust infrastructure.

If the alerting requirements are simple enough (no need to correlate between events, get data from other resources, etc) it might even make sense to use Kafka (or other messaging system) directly.

While checking alternatives we have also made an investigation of S4 (http://incubator.apache.org/s4/), but, it seems like it does not gain as much momentum as Storm does.

Spark (https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/projects/spark-lightning-fast-cluster-computing/) which is mainly directed to batch processing as hadoop, but, has an initiative directed at stream processing as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth having a look at **[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)**. With Splunk you can monitor and alert in real time. It also supports real-time search and analysis capabilities. Splunk basically captures, indexes and correlates real-time data in a searchable repository from which users can generate graphs, reports, alerts, dashboards and visualizations, which would be a lot easier from an end user's perspective.

Comment: Splunk is a nice solution, but unfortunately, for my requirements I'd have to go for the enterprise version and that's not possible (financial reasons)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [EVAM](http://www.evam.com). It has scenario based designer and multiple scenarios in parallel or sequential can be run for the same stream. Event and action generations are done once, then GUI drag and drop approach can be used to create many scenarios..

Answer (score 0):

For a more ops-oriented solution, you could look at [graylog](http://graylog2.org/) . The downside is that you don't have infinite possibilites like with Storm, so what you can't do you can't code it either (at least not easily, but it's open source).

Also, you could very well use [Centreon](http://www.centreon.com/) for a more complete solution. It all depends if your example was just a random one, or your actual use case (if this is the case, look at ops tools, not programming one. There is a ton of monitoring tools out there.).